# Chrome performance track too much weird offsetWidth and offsetHeight access in stack

Tags: google-chrome, reflow

**getCellMeasurements** seems to cost to much time, Chrome performance shows there its a lot of clientWidth and clientHeight property access
[image]

But there is actually only one place to access clientWidth and clientHeight property .

[image]